# Javascript cant get document.getElementById('cs') from array

Tags: javascript

Edit: This is what my code currently looks like. It's still not working.

```
<head>
<script>
window.onload = myload()
var ids[]
function myload() { 
      alert("hi")
      ids = [document.getElementById('bs'),
        document.getElementById('cs'),
        document.getElementById('ds')
      ]

    }

function border(){
    ids[1].style.border = "9px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body> //elements definded here </body>
```

---

I'm trying to write a function that changes the border of a list of images at a certain interval. However, I can't seem to make it work. 
I am trying to do the following:

```
<head>
<script>
var ids = [document.getElementById('a'), 
           document.getElementById('b'), 
           document.getElementById('c')]

function(x){
    ids[x].border = "9px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body> //elements definded here </body>
```

but it doesn't run. However, when I run:

```
document.getElementById('a').border = "9px"
```

it does work. I'm guessing I'm not calling it properly from the array. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: fixed 'a' twice in the array.

Comment: You have `a` twice and [1] is the b - also I would expect style.border. Also the array has to be defined AFTER the objects have rendered

Comment: shouldn't it be `style.border`?

Comment: Now you changed your question. You are not calling the function

Comment: How are you calling the function? Try naming it and calling it. I see a declaration but it's never used.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in JavaScript are indexed from 0, so doing `ids[0].style.border = "9px";` or `ids[2].style.border = "9px";` Will give you the desired effect. You'll also want to access the `style` property on the element (I've fixed that in the code)

Comment: `depending on which a you want styled.` it shouldn't be possible for them to be *different*. It's a lookup by ID which will return the same HTMLElement. Modifying either will lead to "both" changing.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the original question before the function(x) appeared

1. [1] is the b since JS arrays start at 0
2. I would expect style.border.
3. The array has to be defined AFTER the objects have rendered.
   If you have the array in a script tag before the elements with ids 
   a,b,c exist then you will get the  ids equal to
   `[undefined,undefined,undefined]`

```js
window.onload = function() { // or addEventHandler OR put script before </body>
  var ids = [document.getElementById('a'),
    document.getElementById('b'),
    document.getElementById('a')
  ]
  ids[1].style.border = "9px solid black"; // the second element
}
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
```

Using a function:

```js
var ids=[]; // this is now global in scope

function setIt(idx) {
  ids[idx].style.border = "9px solid black";
}

window.onload = function() { // or addEventHandler OR put script before </body>
  ids = [document.getElementById('a'),
    document.getElementById('b'),
    document.getElementById('a')
  ]
  setIt(1);  // the second element
}
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
```

Fixing your code

```js
window.onload = myload; // removed ()
var ids=[]; // missing an equals

function myload() {
  alert("hi")
  ids = [document.getElementById('bs'),
    document.getElementById('cs'),
    document.getElementById('ds')
  ]
  border();
}

function border() {
  ids[1].style.borderWidth = "9px"; // just setting border is not enough
}
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<div id="bs">A</div>
    <div id="cs">B</div>
    <div id="ds">C</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The array has to be defined AFTER the objects have rendered"

Comment: If you have the array in a script tag before the elements with ids a,b,c exist then you will get `[undefined,undefined,undefined]`

Comment: Hence the onload in my script

Comment: `x= 1 
function(x){
    ids[x].border = "9px";
}` is not valid JS

Comment: Oops my bad. In my code x is passed in. I'll edit it. thanks!

Comment: `window.onload=myload;` without the () and you are not calling border() anywhere. Why not implement my code the way I wrote it?

Comment: @Chip please see my last code which fixes your example